# AMD Ryzen™ 5 3400G drivers for Ubuntu (can't change screen resolution)

Tags: drivers, graphics, display-resolution, amd-graphics, amd-ryzen

On the official website of AMD I couldn't find the drivers for Ubuntu, only for Windows 10 ([AMD Ryzen 5 Driver](https://www.amd.com/es/support/apu/amd-ryzen-processors/amd-ryzen-5-desktop-processors-radeon-vega-graphics/amd-ryzen-5-1)). I can't change my screen resolution, just one option available.

I tried a lot of things; I don't have the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file probably because I can't install AMD drivers. I tried a lot of commands related to `xrandr`, but none worked.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Unfortunately not, there's a lack of Ryzen support in Linux world for some reason it takes AMD too long to release an official driver for Linux. You can [read these articles](https://www.x.org/wiki/RadeonFeature/#index11h2) about AMD open source drivers.

Comment: I recommend you to use pre-installed Ubuntu configuration. Or read through the documentation in my previous comment.

Comment: This CPU/APU has only just come out and will need kernel support I suspect....

Answer (score 2):

I just bought the new 3400G and I run into the same problem

https://github.com/M-Bab/linux-kernel-amdgpu-binaries
Clone or download -> Download zip

```
sudo dpkg -i [linux-headers-name].deb [linux-image-name].deb firmware-radeon-ucode_*_all.deb
sudo update-grub
sudo reboot
```

Thats it
I would like to give the kiss to whoever make that available man

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issues with AMD Ryzen 5 3400g and Ubuntu 18.04.
In my case I also wanted to connect second display. I spend hours working on the bios and different drivers to no avail. Finally I found the solution, just upgrade the kernel above 4.15. At the time of writing I managed to upgrade the kernel to 5.0. It really helped, I can change resolution and connect multiple displays.

To check what kernel you have:

```
uname -a
```

To upgrade kernel:

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04
```

Finally reboot the system.

Answer (score 1):

Neither upgrading to 5.0 nor installing the linux-kernel-amdgpu-binaries linked above worked for me. I finally got my system running as expected after installing the 5.4.12 kernel using ubuntu kernel utility tools and NOT installing any additional drivers under Ubuntu 19.04.