# AMD Ryzen 5 3400G on Linux Ubuntu 18.04 (HDMI fails at 60 Hz refresh rate)

Tags: 18.04

I just bought a new 3400G (**AMD Ryzen 5 3400G** with Radeon Vega 11 Graphics) and the **60 Hz refresh configuration** is not working via HDMI. At **30 Hz all works ok**, but when I put 60Hz on refresh rate at 3840x2160 the hdmi signal randomly disapears and then reappear, or it shows random ghost lines on the TV.

The HDMI cable work OK with other devices and support HDMI 2.0. It is the first time that I use 4k at 60Hz on a device. In particular this device is a RCA TS50UHD Smart TV.

I do not tried yet with the steps on https://askubuntu.com/a/1168404/142926. Anyone know if I follow the steps of link above Can I "crash" something, or that option only add an option to grub menu and I can use an older kernel installed for boot in order to go back and use the system with 30 Hz ithout a problem

My actual kernel and Ubuntu version:

```
➜  default uname -a
   Linux L-G580 5.0.0-31-generic #33~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 1 10:20:39 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
➜  default lsb_release -a
   No LSB modules are available.
   Distributor ID:  Ubuntu
   Description: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
   Release: 18.04
   Codename: bionic

 06:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Picasso [1002:15d8] (rev c8) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])

glxinfo | grep OpenGL
OpenGL vendor string: X.Org
OpenGL renderer string: AMD RAVEN (DRM 3.27.0, 5.0.0-31-generic, LLVM 8.0.0)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 19.0.8
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 4.5 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 19.0.8
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: compatibility profile
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 19.0.8
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

I appreciate any help....
Thank You.

Comment: TY for providing the details. 1) Does that HDMI cable work OK with other devices? 2) What is the make and model of the TV you are using as an HDMI monitor? 3) Has it worked OK at 3840x2160@60Hz from a PC before? Please click [edit] and provide that information, to help us help you. Please do not use Add Comment, but instead use [edit].

Comment: Have you updated your firmware (yes even for a new computer)? Get the latest from the vendor, and check regularly for awhile since new things might get a few updates quickly.